# IF and FOR cycle do not print correct values

Tags: matlab, for-loop, if-statement, trigonometry

I have a probably stupid problem but I can't get over it.

The purpose of all this is to have the two variables F_hor_alb and F_ver_alb defined according to the rule reported in the if statement.

If the cosine of that angle (60wt) is greater by an amount in this case equal to -0.37 (shadow) then the two variables must have a sinusoidal trend. Otherwise they are worth zero.

By verifying the outputs of the cosine and of the variables, the first is as it should be, but the variables have all values equal to zero except the first and therefore do not follow the values that the cosine itself assumes.
Is there anything in the IF that doesn't work?

(Fhor and Fver are already defined in another piece of the code).

```
Example of output
Cos(60wt): 0,9980         0,9970 0,9960   .....
F_hor_alb: 0,9980*F_hor     0      0        0     0 0 0 0 0 0 0
F_ver_alb: 0,9980*F_ver     0      0        0     0 0 0 0 0


Re = 6378; % Radius of Earth (km)
z = 500; % Orbital Altitude (km)
mu = 3.986004415e5 % Gravitational constan of Earth (km3/s2)
OrbitalT = 2*pi*sqrt(((Re+z)^3)/mu); % Orbital Period (s)
orbits = 30; % Number of cycles for the simulation
simtime = (OrbitalT*orbits)/60; % Simulation time (min)
simstep = 1; % Sampling step (min)

w=2*pi/OrbitalT; 
F_hor_alb = zeros(ceil(simtime));
F_ver_alb = zeros(ceil(simtime));

for t = 1:simstep:ceil(simtime)
    if cos(w*t*60)>shadow
        F_hor_alb = F_hor*cos(w*t*60);
        F_ver_alb = F_ver*cos(w*t*60);
    else
        F_hor_alb = 0;
        F_ver_alb = 0;
    end

    F_hor_alb(t) = F_hor_alb;
    F_ver_alb(t) = F_ver_alb;
    coseno(t)=cos(w*t*60);
    t=t+1;
end
```

Comment: How do you define shadow, F_hor and F_ver?

Comment: Also, I am not sure what you want to do in these lines:

`F_hor_alb(t) = F_hor_alb;
F_ver_alb(t) = F_ver_alb;
coseno(t)=cos(w*t*60);
 t=t+1;`

t is supposed to be incrementing in the for loop, there is no need to tell Matlab to add one to t.

Comment: 'F_hor_alb = zeros(ceil(simtime));
F_ver_alb = zeros(ceil(simtime));'

What size of a matrix are you expecting here? if you want a vector, you need to define as such:

'F_hor_alb = zeros(ceil(simtime),1);
F_ver_alb = zeros(ceil(simtime),1);'

Comment: Angles are in radians, not degrees for the function `cos`. Use `cosd` for degrees. That 60 is suspicious

Comment: There are so many things wrong with this code, all I can do is suggest you take a quick introduction to MATLAB. Your life will be a lot easier if you learn it the right way, as opposed to assembling random syntax and asking why it is not working. For example: https://matlabacademy.mathworks.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change a few things on your code.

It seems you are having some trouble understanding how the for-loop works in Matlab.

```
Re = 6378; % Radius of Earth (km)
z = 500; % Orbital Altitude (km)
mu = 3.986004415e5 % Gravitational constan of Earth (km3/s2)
OrbitalT = 2*pi*sqrt(((Re+z)^3)/mu); % Orbital Period (s)
orbits = 30; % Number of cycles for the simulation
simtime = (OrbitalT*orbits)/60; % Simulation time (min)
simstep = 1; % Sampling step (min)

w=2*pi/OrbitalT;

F_hor = 1;
F_ver = 2;
shadow = 0.5;

t = (1:simstep:ceil(simtime))';
F_hor_alb = nan(size(t));
F_ver_alb = nan(size(t));
coseno = nan(size(t));

for i = 1:length(t)
    if cos(w*t(i)*60)>shadow
        disp('here');
        F_hor_alb(i) = F_hor*cos(w*t(i)*60);
        F_ver_alb(i) = F_ver*cos(w*t(i)*60);
    else
        F_hor_alb(i) = 0;
        F_ver_alb(i) = 0;
    end

    coseno(i)=cos(w*t(i)*60);
end
```

Comment: You really helped me solving the problem, but I've actually changed few points of my previous code.
The variables you defined were already defined in other parts of the code.
I don't use the nan in the preamble because it's a light simulation and there should be no need.
You helped me to take a bit of rust off =). Thanks!

`for t = 1:simstep:ceil(simtime)
    if cos(w*t*60)>shadow
        F_hor_alb(t) = F_hor*cos(w*t*60);
        F_ver_alb(t) = F_ver*cos(w*t*60);
    else
        F_hor_alb(t) = 0;
        F_ver_alb(t) = 0;
    end
   
    coseno(t)=cos(w*t*60);
end`

Comment: The nan is a good practice to differentiate the zeros that are actual zeros to the code working unexpectedly. That would have given you a hint that the code was not working as you expected ;)

Comment: Alternatively, you can use zeros if you want to "save" some cpu.

Then you just do the following:

`if cos(w*t(i)*60)>shadow
        disp('here');
        F_hor_alb(i) = F_hor*cos(w*t(i)*60);
        F_ver_alb(i) = F_ver*cos(w*t(i)*60);
    end`. Using this approach you avoid having the else and you avoid one assignment operation. Having that said, I prefer the approach using nan, as it makes the whole thing more explicit.